# JSF related project facets not appearing in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, eclipse, jsf, jsf-2, eclipse-juno

I'm trying to create a dynamic web project with JSF 2.0 configuration in **Eclipse Java EE Juno SR1**. **I have installed WTP tools** from http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno/.

**I use Java 1.6**

I face the following problems :

**1. I don't have JSF facets in my eclipse**

[image]

**2. Also, even after installing WTP tools, I don't get a web page editor.**

[image]

**3 . On a related note, I'm trying to use JBoss AS 7.1 Application server with eclipse, but I am not able to find it's adapter either.**

[image]

I use Eclipse Juno with Java 1.6

Comment: You shouldn't have the need to install WTP separately when you already have downloaded Eclipse IDE for Java EE (with the EE). Apparently you've messed up its default trim. Delete everything and unpack the downloaded Eclipse for Java EE once again and don't attempt to install WTP.

Comment: @BalusC - I did this and I still have all the three problems that I described above.